# AVAudioRecorder.pause() shows red mic icon in the status bar

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation, recording

I am working on audio recorder app and I use AVAudioRecorder to record audio.

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-record-audio-using-avaudiorecorder

Everything works fine.
To record audio when app is in the background, I enabled **'audio' background mode**. Now the problem appears. Whenever I stop recording, it shows red mic icon in the status bar for less than 1s even the app is in foreground now.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfHzh.jpg

If I disable 'audio' background mode, this doesn't appear.

Source code: https://github.com/nightbird8n/AudioRecorder

Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks

Comment: If an app uses the microphone in the background then iOS lets the user know this, it shouldn't happen without the user knowing, its a privacy feature.

Comment: The red icon should be shown if the app is in background state. This is right. But the problem is that the red icon is shown even when the app is in foreground state when I stop recording. It shows less than 1s.

Comment: This is super annoying!